# Selenium RC using Grails unable to open URL

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

My Selenium RC code is launching the browser but it is taking me to C:\Users\Kanishka\AppData\Local\Temp\customProfileDir3e16427300054effa807e843dd1a332f\core\Blank.html instead of the intended URL.

The code I have written is very simple and I am using all default Selenium settings.

```
import grails.plugins.selenium.*
import org.junit.*
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*

@Mixin(SeleniumAware)
class NewTests extends GroovyTestCase 
{
    void testHomepageLoads() 
    {
        selenium.start()
        selenium.open("http://www.google.co.in/")
        assertTrue selenium.isTextPresent("Welcome to Grails")
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Selenium are you using?  Are you trying to launch IE?

Comment: user1728, welcome to SQA.  It may be easier to help you if you can update your question with the version of Selenium you are using.  My guess is that this problem is environmental and does not have anything to do with Grails.

Comment: hi. i got it to work. i just changed url from *iexplore to *iexploreproxy in the seleniumconfig.groovy file. thanks a lot

Comment: You should really look into upgrading to WebDriver - its more stable. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 2):

From the OP, via comment:

> I got it to work. I just changed the url from *iexplore to *iexploreproxy
>   in the seleniumconfig.groovy file.